# Android Google map balloon over overlayitem

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, balloon

I am using google map, displaying overlayitems on the google map.

To create balloon effect, i am using customize view and using geopoints with MapView.LayoutParams to display it at particular location.

overlayitem's icon and baloon both having same geopoint thats why they both are overriding eatch other.

I want to display baloon over the overlayitem icon look like it should point to the icon.

Follwing is my code

```
MapView.LayoutParams mapParams = new MapView.LayoutParams(MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, mapEvent.getGeoPoint(), MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);
```

[image]

I want to display baloon like following please tell me should i decrease lat long to make it top ? or should i change the layout param.Bottom or what i tried different variation not working like following

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880623/how-to-show-a-balloon-above-a-marker-in-a-mapactivity-isnt-there-a-widget 

check this too, so useful.