# How to show a balloon above a marker in a MapActivity? Isn't there a widget?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I dont get the point, why I have to code so much for it. Like, I dont want to care about...

- the position of the balloon (I just want to assign a geopoint)
- the layout of a basic balloon (Later on I might want to implement a xml based layout)
- the number of shown
  balloons (only display one at a time)
- the open/close
  behaviour of the balloon (close, when an other bollon is tabbed)

**Update**

Solved it! See my answer below...

Comment: "He is using constructs I only now from Javascript...maybe he is dynamicly creating a linearLayout or smth." -- no, I think that answer is just for the Web-based Google Maps, not for the Android `MapView`. "I dont get the point, why I have to code so much for it. Like, I dont want to care about the position of the balloon and the number of shown balloons and the open/close behaviour." -- the "google example" shows markers and a dialog, and does not "show a balloon with information, when a marker is clicked". If you want *less* code, we cannot help you.

Comment: oh ok, than the answer I was refering to cant match the question, which is tagged with "Android" and "Android-SDK".

The google example so far is pretty easy with small effort of code. E.g. they don't calculate the position on the screen for the marke position. Thats making me think, that there must be an easy way to implement balloons.

Comment: @Quintin Robinson: Thanks for revising the title. Tell me the reason, why u removed [Android]? Is it enough to just add the Tag "android"? If there is a stackoverflow rule to do so, I will apply that for future questions.

Comment: Yes, the convention is not to inorganically tag the question with the tag that it already applies to, however if you can include the tag in the title organically then it isn't an issue.. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61055/when-should-we-remove-pseudo-tags-from-a-title/61059#61059 and many other Meta conversations on writing good titles.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/howto-writing-good-titles

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Here is the "the missing widget"...**

[image]

- Balloons without icons:
  https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons#readme
- Balloons with icons (extends Jeff
  Gilfelt's project):
  <strike>https://github.com/galex/android-mapviewballoons</strike> (Offline, see comments to this answer)

Comment: the 'galex' project (second link) is no longer active. Any idea if it exists in some form somewhere?

Comment: @StealthRabbi AFAIK it was merged to the Jeff's project (first link): https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons/pull/3