# Animation around Itemized Overlay

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an application which makes use of google map. I have some overlays added to show location of certain places. These overlay items can tap to get more information. I followed the link [How to show a balloon above a marker in a MapActivity? Isn't there a widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880623/how-to-show-a-balloon-above-a-marker-in-a-mapactivity-isnt-there-a-widget) to achieve. Besides, I need to show some animation around the overlay item to show that it is being selected.

I have one idea which is to draw some circles(just stroke, without fill) simultaneously one after another. Start from small circle with thicker stroke to big circle with thinner stroke. When the second circle is drawn, the first circle should disappear. It would be like circle gradually growing (ripple effect) . Of course, it would disappear and start the process over again.

I am having trouble with drawing circles on the mapview. Is it just another overlay or something else? I would be grateful if anyone could show me similar thread or recommendation. Any suggestion are welcome too.