# Map in android application project

Tags: java, android, sqlite, dictionary

I want to use the map in my android app project. Please anyone tell me how to create the map in my project ? In which class i have to create the map and how can i insert the values in it ? I just want to use the city names and their codes in my project and want to enter the city code as key and city name as value .For example: DEL is city code and Delhi is its Value.

Comment: use new boston website , best and easiest tutorial go to the link ===>>>http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6 and see android video tutorial video 129 to 141 , its all about maps

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mapview balloons for more flexibility.

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

Answer (score 0):

For display MAP in your android application you have to use `MapView` in android.

You can find example [here](http://androiddevelopement.blogspot.in/2011/06/android-google-map-application-example.html).

Also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4143694/1405983).

Comment: which one first or second ?

Comment: as i am new to android so plz tell me is der any need to install any tool or library for using maps?

Comment: You have to first get your MD5 certificate fingerprint....Please go through step by step [I have add link for that in answer](http://androiddevelopement.blogspot.in/2011/06/android-google-map-application-example.html)