# How to show InfoWindow using Android Maps Utility Library for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer

I'm using [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/) in order to show several markers in a map in a clustered way.
I've followed the instructions to make it work, as well as taking a look at the examples in the library, but I can't figure out how to show an `InfoWindow` when a marker is clicked.

I guess `getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);` is the one managing the `onClick` events, and if commented out, I can override it using `getMap().setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {));` but I have no access to my custom marker object.
Nevertheless, if I use `getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);`, I can't find a way to show the `InfoWindow` when a marker has been clicked.

Does anybody have any idea about how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You mean a balloon like this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880623/how-to-show-a-balloon-above-a-marker-in-a-mapactivity-isnt-there-a-widget

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899619/opening-infowindow-automatically-when-adding-marker-google-maps-v2-android
Think this will help you.

Comment: @Tristan the first link is deprecated. The second one doesn't work, since the method here is `onClusterClick(Cluster<MarkerItem> cluster)` and as you see MarkerItem is a custom object of mine and doesn't have the a `showInfoWindow()` method

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to extend the `DefaultClusterRenderer` class and override the `onBeforeClusterItemRendered`, attaching the title to the MarkerOptions object passed as argument.

After that, you can pass your implementation to the `ClusterManager`.

Example:

```
class MyItem implements ClusterItem {

    private LatLng mPosition;
    private String mTitle;

    public MyItem(LatLng position){
        mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return mPosition;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }
}

class MyClusterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem> {

    public MyClusterRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map,
            ClusterManager<MyItem> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);

        markerOptions.title(item.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClusterItemRendered(MyItem clusterItem, Marker marker) {
        super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker);

        //here you have access to the marker itself
    }
}
```

And then  you can use it in this way:

```
ClusterManager<MyItem> clusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, getMap());
clusterManager.setRenderer(new MyClusterRenderer(this, getMap() ,clusterManager));
```

Comment: is there any way to define a custom `InfoWindow` to show, or you can only show the default one?

Comment: Thanks. Why you call super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered? Apart from, I want to avoid centering the item/cluster in screen when is tap, so I return true in onClusterClick and onClusterItemClick. The problem is that if I return true, the info window is not shown, but it it's false, is shown (but firstly is centered). Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RiccardoCiovati I am not seeing any info window after implementing this. manulorenzo! did you get the info window?