# Google Maps Cluster Customization (Adding text to Cluster Item)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DsWi.png): Example  [image]

This picture represents a group of clusters(the ones that have the text in the middle) and a cluster Item, which is only one item of a specific type.

What I'm trying to achieve is that on a cluster item, I want to add some text, for example "1", which represents that is only a cluster item, therefore there is only one item in there.

I managed to get the text working on the group of clusters but not on the cluster item.

The code that does the trick in my case it's this one:

```
String place = item.getPlaceName();
            if (place.length() > 12)
                place = place.substring(0, 10) + "..";
            placeAddressAndLocation.setText(place);
```

Now I am not aware where should I place the exact code for the cluster item.

In the example found on google dev(which is the one I'm also following), there are a couple of methods for these

```
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered

protected void onClusterItemRendered
```

Tried adding the code on both of the methods, but it doesn't do anything. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `onBeforeClusterItemRendered`, you can try with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21877489/4195406).

So in the `onBeforeClusterItemRendered` method, you can set the attributes of markerOptions.

You might want to try to set the title, snippet or icon of the markerOptions, you can read [the documentation of the markerOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html).

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to display an infoWindow, basically I'm trying to set some text to a cluster with one item. I got this working for a cluster with multiple items though

Comment: Can you include more codes about how you make one cluster with multiple items working? Also a screenshot of your current screen will be nice.

Comment: It's fixed!

A cluster is declared twice, like this:

  private View checkinView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.frame_checkincluster, null);
        private View clusterView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.frame_checkincluster, null);

One of the declarations is for the Clusters while the other one is for the Cluster Items :)